# Can't use the data returned by JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, sails.js, supertest

I'm trying to test an api (sails.js) and I can't use the data returned by JSON.parse

I have this test:

```
describe('when requesting resource /coin', function () {

it ('should request "/Coin" on server and return it', function (done) {
  supertest(sails.express.app)
    .get('/Coin')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(200, done)
    .end(function(err, res) {
      var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.text));
      assert.equal(result.cash, 1000);
      done();
    })
  })
 })
```

Here you can see how result looks like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [
>
> {
>
> "userId": "macario",
>
> "cash": 1000,
>
> "createdAt": "2014-03-04T20:17:57.483Z",
>
> "updatedAt": "2014-03-07T02:47:51.098Z",
>
> "id": 15
>
> }
>
> ][
>
> {
>
> "userId": "macario",
>
> "cash": 1000,
>
> "createdAt": "2014-03-04T20:17:57.483Z",
>
> "updatedAt": "2014-03-07T02:47:51.098Z",
>
> "id": 15
>
> }
>   ]

And the error:

> Uncaught AssertionError: "undefined" == 1000

I would like to use this informations, but i can't access them.

Comment: Why you do something like this       ```var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.text));``` ?

Comment: I have no idea. I was following a tutorial but it was focused on node then i tried to adapt some commands. If there's an easy way for retrieving the data and using it thats what i need. Im starting with this and its a very simple api just for learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response in `res.text` is probably a string.

When you `stringify` a string the quotes become escaped, resulting in this;

```
""[{\"userId\":\"macario\",\"cash\":1000,\"createdAt\":\"2014-03-
04T20:17:57.483Z\",\"updatedAt\":\"2014-03-07T02:47:51.098Z\",\"id\":15}]""
```

So when you call `JSON.parse` on it, it just turns it back into a String, instead of into the Object you want.

Just change this line;

```
var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.text));
```

to this;

```
var result = JSON.parse(res.text);
```

If the `parse` fails then the JSON in `res.text` is malformed and that is your main problem.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this before but as you said, the problem is with the format in fact.

The error given is:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

I thinks thats caused by the brackets [] that wrap the json, i'm trying to remove them

Comment: The brackets should be fine; they represent an array.  However in your question I don't see a comma between the first element in the array and the second, which would cause the error.  Also, your test doesn't look quite right--you are doing a `find` request that returns *all* coins (hence the array), but checking for the `cash` value as if you're expecting only one result.  Either check `result[0].cash`, or change the request to `/Coin/15` (or some other known ID)

Comment: I have finally found the error. I was receiving double quotes in the returned json, I just changed
     .expect(200, done) 
to
     .expect(200) and it worked :D